# Outlook Addin does not work in shared mailbox in new Outlook on Mac

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed a small Outlook plugin that is supposed to be used in a shared mailbox.

The problems are the following:

In the "new" Outlook for mac it can only be opened one time, in the shared Mailbox. After that the Addin is greyed out.

In Outlook on the web the pinning feature can not be used in the shared mailbox

The details:

I added

```
<DesktopFormFactor>
  <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
```

to the manifest, to make it work within a shared mailbox.

One of our users uses a mac and switched to "new Outlook".  When he is in the shared mailbox the Addin can be opened once. (Right after opening the personal mailbox) After that the Icon is greyed out and it cant be opened again (only when switching to the personal mailbox and back) . When hovering over the Addin, this message appears:

[image] (Changed the icon, title and email)

In the "old" Outlook for Mac it does seem to work, but the user does not want to use it.

At first i thought maybe it has something to do with the WebApplicationInfo and its authorization but it shows the same behavior without this part.

Interestingly it does also work for a while after a fresh installation. If I freshly add the manifest.xml it can be used for one or two sessions.

In the web client a different problem occurs, the Addin can be loaded in the shared mailbox but the pinning does not work.

Here is the full manifest (without urls and names), I am aware that it does not include a version for the older Outlook versions. But our user base is very limited and everybody uses the latest client.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
    <Id>{{ID}}</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>{{Provider}}</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="{{Name}"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="{{Description}"/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://test.app/Icon"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://test.app/Icon2"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://test.app/Help"/>

    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://test.app/</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://test.app/pane"/>
                <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
    </Rule>
    <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Requirements>
                <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
                </bt:Sets>
            </Requirements>
            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>

                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                    <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                        <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                                            <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>

                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>


                    </DesktopFormFactor>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
            <Resources>
                <bt:Images>
                    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://test.app/Icon1"/>
                    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://test.app/Icon2"/>
                    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://test.app/Icon3"/>
                </bt:Images>
                <bt:Urls>
                    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://test.app/Pane"/>
                </bt:Urls>
                <bt:ShortStrings>
                    <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue=""/>
                </bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:LongStrings>
                    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
                </bt:LongStrings>
            </Resources>
            <WebApplicationInfo>
                <Id>{{ID}}</Id>
                <Resource>{{URI}}</Resource>
                <Scopes>
                    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
                    <Scope>openid</Scope>
                    <Scope>profile</Scope>
                    <Scope>Mail.ReadWrite.Shared</Scope>
                    <Scope>Mail.Send.Shared</Scope>
                    <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
                </Scopes>
            </WebApplicationInfo>
        </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Diagnostics ID. The reason for Add-ins not working in the Shared mailbox is that shared folder support is not yet enabled in Production. We have documented the unsupported features in Production here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/compare-outlook-add-in-support-in-outlook-for-mac#add-in-support-in-outlook-on-new-mac-ui-preview.

Comment: Shared mailbox support is now available in Insiders Fast versions. We recommend you to try the latest Insiders version and let us know if the issue gets resolved. Documentation on joining Insiders:https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/mac

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I installed the version from the  beta channel. (16.49 21041800). Same behaviour. Can be opened one time, after that it greys out.

Comment: The MS addIns (like OneNote) on the other hand do work. We also installed DocuSign from the store and it can be used in the shared mailbox.

Comment: Does the issue occur only when Add-in is pinned to the toolbar? Could you please try unpinning the Add-in using the 'Customize Toolbar' Option and check if Add-in gets enabled?

Comment: You are right. If the AddIn is not attached to the tool bar it works. If I unpinn it from the toolbar the icon stays enabled.

Comment: So we will work with the unpinned icon until the bug is fixed. Thank you. Do you also have an idea about the second problem: When I open the AddIn in Outlook on the web I can pin the Addin, but only in the personal mailbox. In the shared mailbox it unpins itself every time I change the selected item.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation regarding Add-in Pinning in Mac Outlook. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point.
Internal tracking id: Office 2080513.


Regarding Outlook on the web, Could you please clarify the below points?
1. By Pinning, are you referring to taskpane pinning or Add-in icon pinning in the toolbar?
2. Could you please specify the steps followed in opening the shared mailbox.

Comment: I mean pinning the addIn sidebar to not close when a different email is selected. The bar (as you can see in the maifest) is configured as                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>

Comment: This also works in the personal mailbox. But in the shared mailbox the pane always closes when a different mail is selected.

Comment: When you say shared mailbox, do you mean a mailbox which is shared among a group of people or is it a shared folder which a user shares with his/her delegate?

Comment: It is a shared mailbox but in Outlook for web you can add it as a folder "Add Shared Folder". Right click on folders.

Comment: Otherwise one would need to click on the User and "Open a different mailbox" but then the Addin can not be used entirely since an addin can only be installed in an users mailbox and not in shared mailboxes (as far as I understood)

Comment: Addins support for group shared mailbox is not yet supported on Outlook on Web. This is mentioned in our documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access). 

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addins support for group shared mailbox is not yet supported on Outlook on Web. This is mentioned in our documentation here. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process

Comment: Funny thing is, they do work. The AddIn can be loaded and also works in the web version. The only thing that does not work is pinning within the shared mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the info, at least we got the workaround in the new Outlook for Mac which was the more important issue.

Comment: @David installing the addins in shared mailboxes would yield this error. 'The operation on mailbox failed because it's out of the current user's write scope.' How were you able to get past this? thanks

Comment: We installed the addin in the users mailbox (not in the shared one) but then they could then use it in shared mailboxes they have access to.